# denwer "зависает" на windows 10

Tags: html, css, apache, denwer

Пишу сайт, и очень часто выходит так, что при обновлении страницы localhost/*имя_папки_сайта не происходит изменений, которые были внесены в файлы самого сайта. Проверял во всех браузерах - куча свойств css попросту не отображается (отображается предыдущая версия файла css, но я определенно точно сохранил его). Перезагрузка сервера не помогает - решить проблему получается лишь перезагрузив компьютер (и после перезагрузки и запуска сервера эти изменения в css наконец-то вступают в силу), либо подождав 10 минут после изменения файла. Проблема сохранилась на двух компьютерах под windows 10, которые ни коем образом не связаны между собой. Минут 15 все отлично работает, и потом виснет. PS использую sublime text, если открыть папку с файлом css , и открыть его блокнотом - изменения есть. PPS так же проблема решается, если я создаю копию css файла (с изменениями) и прикрепляю ее вместо основного в html

Comment: Это кэш браузера. При загрузке css добавляйте к ним антикэш, например, так: *css/styles.css?123*, где 123 - ваша версия файла. Т.е. при каждом изменении css обновляйте этот параметр и тогда браузер будет подгружать актуальную версию файла

Comment: CTRL+F5 спасет мир

Comment: Кажется, денвер отстает от системы по времени и неправильно отдает кэширующие заголовки. Или вообще не настроен для этого. Если работаете в Mozilla, включайте панель разработки - тогда кэш отключается. P.S. Пробовали Open Server? Может, с ним будет всё хорошо...

Comment: @Никита: Котеров и Ко давно забросили свой продукт Denwer - версия PHP 5.3 далеко несвежая. Для windows используйте [Open Server](http://open-server.ru/) или [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/ru/index.html). Когда станет "тесно", то гипервизор (VirtualBox и ему подобные) c Linux, либо сразу на Linux.